# Button Click no result

Tags: c#, cmd, adb

I was following a tutorial on XDA [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2042227] in regards to setting up your own android ADB GUI Toolkit in C#. I have the GUI setup right as we speak and the code compiles correctly but when I click the install APK button it does not install the APK to my device.

```
    private void InstallAPK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c adb install " + textBox1.Text);
        process.WaitForExit();
        MessageBox.Show(".APK is Installed", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```

No errors are found in this code it all works but its not actually executing the ADB command as it is told to. - Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: TB1 is auto filled with the path to the APK I am trying to install (After I browse / select it of course). I know that part works.

Comment: double check that your file path/name does not contain spaces or add quotation marks around the file name. also capture `stdout` and `stderr` of your adb command to help with trouble-shooting

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks for making me look into that! Spaces were the issue if you would kindly make that a full answer I would gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks around the file name - otherwise it would not properly process file names containing spaces.